# Сказуемое: составное или простое?

Tags: синтаксис

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в данных предложениях сказуемые  являются простыми глагольными, а не составными:
Кто разрешил тебе уйти?
Кто велел тебе рвать цветы в моем саду?
Муромский предложил им осмотреть перед обедом сад.
А вы приезжайте ко мне завтра поговорить о проекте.

Comment: А какие у Вас соображения на этот счет? Вообще-то домашние задания (в широком понимании) тут делать за других не принято.

Comment: Вопрос как не соответствует нормам сайта.

Answer (score 1):

```
почему в данных предложениях сказуемые являются простыми глагольными,
 а не   составными
```

Кто (что сделал?) разрешил(сказуемое простое глагольное) тебе(что разрешил?) уйти(дополнение)? Кто-то разрешил, а делать будешь ты.

Кто (что сделал?)велел(сказуемое простое глаг.) тебе (что велел?)рвать цветы в моем саду?Кто-то велел,а рвать будешь ты, это не действие того, кто велел.

Муромский (что сделал?)предложил им (что предложил?)осмотреть(дополнение) перед обедом сад.Муромский предложил,а осматривать будут они, это не действие Муромского.

А вы (что сделайте?)приезжайте ко мне завтра(зачем? с какой целью?) поговорить (обстоятельство цели)о проекте.

Составные глагольные сказуемые обозначают действие 1 лица: я хотел уйти - я хотел и я бы ушёл.Муромский должен был осмотреть - его действие. Вы хотите поговорить?- ваше действие.Это всё составные глагольные сказуемые, сотоящие из вспомогательного глагола и инфинитива.

Answer (score -1):

Отличие простого глагольного сказуемого от составного глагольного заключается в том, что последнее состоит из двух частей: 
а) вспомогательная часть (глагол в спрягаемой форме) выражает грамматическое значение (время и наклонение);
б) основная часть (неопределённая форма глагола – инфинитив) выражает лексическое значение.

**Напр.:  Я начал петь; Я хочу петь; Я боюсь петь.**

Если в сочетании «глагол + инфинитив» глагол знаменательный, то он один является простым глагольным сказуемым, а инфинитив – второстепенный член предложения.

> То же касается и ваших примеров: в них глагол знаменательный, а инфинитив - второстепенный член предложения.

Comment: Во-первых, не стоит за людей домашнее задание выполнять, во вторых, если уж делаете, то по сути. Определения, которыми невозможно воспользоваться, тут не нужны. "Я разрешил уйти" и "Я решил уйти" - чем один глагол "знаменательнее" другого?!

Comment: Надо бы удалить Ответ, а потом прикончить и Вопрос-задание!

Comment: Во-первых, то что для вас д/з, для меня не д/з. Ваша воля, так все вопросы, которые вам не нравятся, вы будете закрывать. Во-вторых, если чего-то не понимаете, не надо строить из себя умного.